# mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I created a custom timer component, but I got errors about vuex store.
This component starts a timer when it's created and put into the store, then each minute it increments the time. If the person leaves the page like the timer is in the store, the time is saved and when the person comes back to the page, the timer resume by itself.

[image: error from console]

This is my component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-icon v-if="timer.visibility" :color="timeColor" @click="changeTimer">
      {{ $icons.clock }}
    </v-icon>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    id: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      timer: {
        actif: false,
        visibility: false,
        timeOut: null,
        dateDebut: null,
        id: 0
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    listeTimer() {
      return this.$store.state.listeTimerPointage
    },
    timeColor() {
      return this.timer.actif ? 'green' : 'red'
    },
    count: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit('input', val)
      }
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.stopTimer()
  },
  created() {
    let precedentTimer = null
    if (this.id > 0) {
      if (this.listeTimer.length > 0) {
        precedentTimer = this.listeTimer.filter((f) => f.id === this.id)
      }
    } else {
      this.timer.id = 0
    }
    this.startTimer(precedentTimer)
  },
  methods: {
    // Start le timer
    startTimer(precedentTimer) {
      if (precedentTimer !== null) {
        this.timer = precedentTimer
        this.count = precedentTimer.count
      } else {
        this.count = 1
        this.timer.dateDebut = new Date()
        if (this.timer.timeOut === null) {
          this.timer.actif = true
          this.timer.visibility = true
          this.timer.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
            this.timerBoucle()
          }, 60000)
        }
      }
      // this.listeTimer.push(this.timer)
      this.$store.commit('addListeTimerPointage', this.timer)
    },
    // Arrete le timer
    stopTimer() {
      this.timer.actif = false
      clearTimeout(this.timer.timeOut)
    },
    // Met en place la boucle toute les 1 minutes
    timerBoucle() {
      const now = new Date()
      const diff = now - this.timer.dateDebut
      this.count += Math.round(diff / 60000)
      this.timer.dateDebut = new Date()
      this.timer.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
        this.timerBoucle()
      }, 60000)
    },
    // Modifie l'état du timer
    changeTimer() {
      this.timer.actif = !this.timer.actif
      if (!this.timer.actif) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer.timeOut)
      } else {
        this.timer.dateDebut = new Date()
        this.timer.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
          this.timerBoucle()
        }, 60000)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I indeed mutate a state, but I don't think I change the state directly

And this is the store:

```
addListeTimerPointage(state, data) {
   state.listeTimerPointage.push(data)
},
deleteTimer(state, data) {
   const newArray = state.listeTimerPointage.filter(
       (item) => item.id !== data
   )
   state.listeTimerPointage = newArray
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use dispatch from component, commit is used only inside action

Comment: Now i have an error:
vuex.esm.js?2f62:497 [vuex] unknown action type: addListeTimerPointage

I thought dispatch was for calling an Action of the store ?

Comment: Being it a good practice is questionable, but you can absolutely use commit from the component: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Comment: It seems to start from this line `return this.$store.state.listeTimerPointage` can you use getters instead? this computed data is used by a filter and that content is assigned to precedentTimer. And content from that is extracted to a variable which is later mutated.

Comment: I did the change, but same issue again,i do think it's coming from the $store.commit, but i don't understand why. In other project i already did commit that way and it never raised issues.
```listeTimer() {
      return this.$store.getters.getterListeTimers
    },
```
And i added the getter in the store
```
getterListeTimers(state) {
      return state.listeTimerPointage
    }
```